# How to return some data from a page in flutter using Navigator 2.0?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm using flutter navigator 2.0 in my app and I'm trying to return some data from another screen when it pops. Here's the code for the same:

This is what I'm using to push/add a new page. After the user has made changes to the edit profile page, I'm trying to update the data on the existing page (profile page).

```
appState.currentAction = PageAction(
  state: PageState.addPage,
  widget: EditProfile(currentUserId: currentUserId),
  page: Edit_Profile_PageConfig,
);
```

After the changes are made on the edit profile page, this is what I'm doing to pop:

`appState.currentAction = PageAction(state: PageState.pop);`

But I'm not sure how can I pass the data from the edit profile page back to the profile page. In the old navigator style, it was pretty easy to have a then function, like this:

```
var callBack = await Navigator.push(
        context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => EditProfile( )));
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve this using Navigator 2.0. I referred to these two references for developing the navigation in the app.

1. [Flutter Navigator 2.0](https://www.raywenderlich.com/19457817-flutter-navigator-2-0-and-deep-links)
2. [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q0jx0l4-xymph9O6zLaOY4d_f7YFpNWX_eGbzYxr9wY/edit#heading=h.v16gxfndiaz1)

Comment: [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/navigator2/demo1.dart) might help you on startup

Answer (score 1):

when calling navigator.pop add your data as a second argument.

```
Navigator.pop(context, data);
```